# Regex for Javascript for [quote]

Tags: javascript, regex

How do i find these?

- [quote#12]
- [quote#15]
- [quote#17]

How do I use regex to find character which have '[quote#]' ??

Comment: What have you tried? This is covered by any basic regular expression tutorial.

Comment: [JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: @DanteSparda: http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you step back from what you're doing and take 30 minutes or so to [read up on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). This is a fairly trivial application of them.

In JavaScript, you can do it like this:

```
var match, value;
match = /\[quote#([^\]]+)\]/.exec(yourString);
value = match && match[1];
```

Comment: I *think* the OP meant something like `/\[([^\]]+)\]/` instead of a literal `/quote#\d+/`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: My original answer just used `.`, but Neils edited it to `[0-9]` which does match what the OP lists as values. I like yours better, though, one sec.

Comment: I saw your original postings, but I was wondering whether the OP meant "any text between brackets" or "quote followed by `#` followed by a number" or something different. The question is ambigious and does not have any context.

Comment: I have to admit i never pay much attention on regex until now. Your answer and some sarcasm advise woke me up..thanks!

Comment: @hypokerit: I wasn't trying to be sarcastic, it was a genuine recommendation. Sorry if it came across that way. Glad this helped, in any case! Best,